# Finding the optimal threshold parameter

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares, optimization, threshold

Assume we are penalizing the least squares by the hard thresholding penalty:
$argmin_\theta 2^{-1}(z_2-\theta)^2 + p_\lambda(|\theta|)$ where $p_\lambda(|\theta|)$ is the hard thresholding penalty defined by $z^2 + (|z|-\lambda)^2 1(|\theta| <\lambda)$. I mean by $z_2$ the least squares estimation and by $\theta$ the estimation of $z_2$ and which correspond to be the thresholding version of it.

The solution of the above equation gives: $ \theta'~ = S_\lambda (z_2)$ = $|z_2|1(|z_2|>\lambda)$ where $_\lambda$ is a threshold value >=0 and $1$ is an indicator function.

The big problem in thresholding is to find the best value of $\lambda$. Most of researchers serve to apply some kinds of cross-validation in order to find the optimal value of $\lambda$. But this can be so computationally expensive in large dimensionality.

That is why, I am trying to find the optimal value of the threshold by minimizing the loss function based on the Frobinius distance between $S_\lambda (z_2)$ and the true value $z$:

$L(S_\lambda (z_2) - z) = E||S_\lambda (z_2) - z||$.

Can someone please tell me how can I compute this formula. What are the brief mathematical steps to do in the minimization of this loss function in order to get the optimal value of $\lambda$??

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you write out a formula for explicitly computing the loss function?  If not, do you know how to compute it if provided the input argument(s)?  Is it a continuous function of its argument(s)?  Does it have continuous derivatives of 1st order?  And of 2nd order?  What constraints do you have?  If you can write out exactly what your optimization problem is (you need to be clear what are optimization (i.e., decision) variables, what are input parameters, what is objective function, what are constraints) , I can provide guidance on how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The problem is that even $z$ is not known. That is why I think it is impossible to resolve this minimization problem.

Comment: I don't understand (know) what your optimization problem is defined to be.  So you need to write out your optimization problem very clearly.  You need to state what the objective function is, making sure to identify which variables are decision, i.e., optimization, variables, what items are inputs (data), and what the constraints on the decision variables are. Perhaps you are thinking of a bilevel optimization problem in which there is an inner optimization problem whose argimin feeds an outer problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization

Comment: You may be able to get help, but you need to more clearly and explicity state the optimization problem you want to solve.

Comment: See https://books.google.com/books?id=3T9LZreZshUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false , and in particular p. 6, for an ideas of what I'm talking about with Bilevel Optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) I will try to know if what I wrote can be resolved or not. If yes, I will edit the question :)